# Does the set of ideals, whose Jacobson radical & nilradicals coincide, form a lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $L(R)$ denote the [lattice of ideals](https://planetmath.org/latticeofideals) of $R$. Let $\mathcal{S}\subseteq L(R)$ be the set of all ideals whose Jacobson radicals and nilradicals coincide.

**Question:** For which classes of rings $\mathcal{S}$ is a sublattice (respectively, $\sigma$-complete or complete sublattice) ?

For example, $\mathcal{S}=L(R)$ iff $R$ is a [Hilbert-Jacobson ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring), so $\mathcal{S}$ is trivially a complete lattice.

---

**Bits:** 1. Let $I,J\in\mathcal{S}$. It is well known that $rad(I\cap J) = rad(I)\cap rad(J)$ and $rad(rad(I)+rad(J)) = rad(I+J)$ for both radicals. Thus, $I\wedge J\in\mathcal{S}$ for any ring, but $I\vee J = I+J$ may not be in $\mathcal{S}$ in general.

2.Within $\mathcal{S}$, we could define $I\vee_S J$ as the *smallest* ideal in $\mathcal{S}$ containing $I+J$. However, we do not know if such an ideal exists for a given pair of ideals $I,J$. For what classes of rings $I\vee_S J$ exists for any $I,J\in\mathcal{S}$?

3.Let $I\subseteq R$ be a semiprimitive ideal, then $I\in\mathcal{S}$. The intersection $J=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I^n$ is not in $\mathcal{S}$ in general. It would be great to know a condition equivalent to $J\in\mathcal{S}$ whenever $I\in\mathcal{S}$ is semiprimitive.

Comment: Note that the question in the title is different from the question in the body--$\mathcal{S}$ could be a lattice without being a sublattice of $L(R)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey First of all, thank you for your reply. I needed to cut my question to make a one-line title that looked rather like a whole paragraph in my first draft. I am more interested in whether $\mathcal{S}$ is a sublattice, although I'd like to know the answer to both if available.